# Fitting 630x32 tire on a rim 622x19 rim

Tags: tire, rims

I was wondering if i would be able to fit my 630x32(27x1 1/4) tire on a 622x19 rim. Seems that the tire is a bit too big for the rim... i didn't think 8mm would make a difference. I know the width is fine as you can fit a 32mm tire on a 19mm rim but for the 630 and 622 im not quite sure.

If this was not clear enough do not hesitate to ask more questions

Thank you

Comment: You might be able to get it to work, but you'd be at risk of a blowout.

Comment: You need to stop thinking and match the numbers. Note that 8mm difference in diameter means 25mm in circumference.  For width, pay attention that tires are flexible in that direction but have fixed diameter.

Answer (score 6):

This will not work. The tire diameter and rim diameter need to match. "Close enough" is not close enough.

Comment: Absolutely will not work. I believe most clincher bicycle rims/tires are a hooked design. If you move the bead outwards 4mm it won't be in the hook in the rim. Also, why even try when ISO 622 tires are so ubiquitous?

Comment: I was not trying Im confused trying to understand the process as my tire clearly states 27 1/4 and 630x30, but 27 1/4 is 692mm and 630 is 24.48 so thats what threw me off. Also my old rim is 25 1/4 and the 27x1 1/4 tire fits. My new rim is 25 on the dot so i would need a 27inch tire since its 1/4 smaller?

Comment: It's true that tire sizes and wheel sizes are incredibly confusing. [This article](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) might help clarify matters (or make matters worse!).

Comment: Thank you very helpful!!

Comment: @MarcPompei Logic simply doesn't apply when converting between tyre measurement systems... where else is a 27" tyre is bigger than a 29" tyre !    On the positive side, the 630 tyres are less common, with a smaller selection.  622 tyres are the most common size, and there's an enormous range of choices.